# How to create a symbolic link for a HTML file in android sd card

Tags: android, html, sd-card

I am creating and storing a Html file in sd card.The html file has custom font(which is also stored in sd card) so when I open the html file from webview I m getting the html content  custom font.

But when I extract/move/copy the Html file from sd card to desktop and open it then the custom font is not working for the html content.

For this Do I need to create any SYMBOLIC LINK for the Html file ?

I want html file to be opened with custom font eventhough I open it from desktop.

How can I achieve this?

Any help is always appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Symlink in not supported by FAT32, so its not possible, first you need to format your SD Card in EXT3 File System then you can do this by Shell Command

```
ln -s /your_file_location/index.html /sdcard/index.html
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Myfile location is in sdcard. So I have given this ln -s /sdcard/test3.html /sdcard/test4.html  and its showing link failed and operation not permitted.

Comment: as I said before you need to format your SDCARD in EXT3 format, then you need a Rooted Android Phone.

Comment: What If I use emulator sd card?